# CMake comparision using LESS_EQUAL in while loop not working

Tags: loops, cmake, comparison

I am trying to get hold of loops in CMake and the following is a sample Prime no test code

```
set(i 2)
set(n 7)
MATH(EXPR cntr ${n}/2)

message(${i}, ${n}, ${cntr})

# When I use `LESS` instead of `LESS_EQUAL` the loop works fine
while(i LESS_EQUAL cntr)
        message("Checking ${i}")
        MATH(EXPR RESULT ${n}%${i})
        if(RESULT EQUAL 0)
                message("${n} is not Prime, as ${n}%${i} is 0")
                break()
        endif()
        MATH(EXPR i ${i}+1)
endwhile()

if(i EQUAL cntr)
        message("${n} is Prime")
endif()
```

The above code with `LESS_EQUAL` is not working for some reason. I think something really silly but tried to debug the code and I am still not getting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohh My bad,

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html

My Cmake version doesn't support the LESS_EQUAL yet so had to convert `LESS_EQUAL` to `i LESS cntr OR i EQUAL cntr`